# push data from web form into CRM 2015 with duplicate detection before creating new records inside CRM

Tags: asp.net, record, dynamics-crm-2013, duplicate-data

Guys.
I have a web form to push metadata into CRM 2015 online by creating new records. But **before creating new records in CRM**, I would like to check if this records(First Name, Last Name, DOB) duplicate or not. If duplicates, updates the existing record, If not, create a new record.

My current idea is, that on the web form(ASP.NET APP) retrieve all records(Names, DOB) and compare with input metadata, if match, updates or creates new record. But I am not sure if there is simple way to do this.

Do you have any suggestion?
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just got it.

bool hasDulicate = false;

```
        //duplicate detection
        FilterExpression codeFilter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        codeFilter.AddCondition("firstname", ConditionOperator.Equal, firstname.Text);
        codeFilter.AddCondition("lastname", ConditionOperator.Equal, lastname.Text);
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "contact",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),  // we assume you want to retrieve all the fields
            Criteria = codeFilter
        };
        EntityCollection records = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        int totalrecords = records.Entities.Count;
        foreach (Entity record in records.Entities)
        {
            if (record["emailaddress1"] != null)
            {
                record["emailaddress1"] = email.Text;
                record["mobilephone"] = phone.Text;
                proxy.Update(record);
                hasDulicate = true;
            }               
        }
        if (hasDulicate == false)
        {
            Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
            contact["firstname"] = Convert.ToString(firstname.Text);
            contact["lastname"] = Convert.ToString(lastname.Text);
            contact["emailaddress1"] = Convert.ToString(email.Text);
            contact["mobilephone"] = Convert.ToString(phone.Text);
            Guid conid = proxy.Create(contact);
        }
```